# How can I roam Sublime Text settings but not roam the open files?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a portable install of sublime text 2 that I sync across machines with skydrive. Roaming the settings through the cloud is great, but when it roams my open files it wrecks things. (because the files don't exist across machines) I definitely want it to remember my open files, but I'd like it to only do it per-machine instead of saved in the cloud. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Excluding the .sublime_session file(s) in `/Data/Settings` should probably do the trick for you. In fact, I think you can go ahead and exclude the entire `/Data/Settings` folder.

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've got that set up by making hard links from the sublime configuration folders to my dropbox folder.

I have a powershell script that, among other things, links the various files:

```
# initialize the sublime preferences
md "$env:appdata/Sublime Text 2/Settings/" -ea SilentlyContinue
ln "$env:appdata/Sublime Text 2/Settings/License.sublime_license" "$HOME/Dropbox/profile/st2/Settings/License.sublime_license"
md "$env:appdata/Sublime Text 2/Installed Packages/" -ea SilentlyContinue
ln "$env:appdata/Sublime Text 2/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package" "$HOME/Dropbox/profile/st2/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package"
new-junction "$env:appdata/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User" "$HOME/Dropbox/profile/st2/User"

foreach ($subfolder in (gci "$HOME/Dropbox/profile/st2/Packages"))
{
    new-junction "$env:appdata/Sublime Text 2/Packages/$subfolder" "$HOME/Dropbox/profile/st2/Packages/$subfolder"
}
```

(I think `new-junction` is an addition added by PSCX.)